# JDBC - Connect Multiple Databases

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am working on an application where I need to connect N number of database systems [N ranges any where between 1 to 350].

The idea is - the user will be presented with a list of databases and will be asked to select any or all of the databases from the list.

Once the databases are selected, I need to connect to each of the database and execute a stored procedure.

I am planning to use plain old JDBC and obtain connection for each of them one a time [or by running them in multiple threads] and execute the store procedure and close the connection.

And all this should happen in a transaction. What is the best way to do this?

If not JDBC...any other efficient way?

Update -

The stored procedure is actually involved in running some sql - for example updating a column, grant permission for a user etc.

Comment: What sort of application? Desktop or web?

Comment: It is a Web Application.

Comment: My understanding is that you don't need to do this in a single transaction, is this true? Else many more needs to be taken into account.

Comment: I am planning to do this in a single transaction....not sure about complexities!

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a threadpool with a reasonable maximum amount of threads, between ten and twenty threads maybe, with help of [`Executors#newFixedThreadPool()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) and invoke the separate DB connecting and SP executing tasks each as a [`Callable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) using [`ExecutorService#invokeAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). You would like to play with the threadcount and profile which yields the best performance after all.

Each `Callable` implementation should take the connection details and SP name as constructor argument so that you can reuse the same implementation for different DB calls.

---

**Update**: OK, it's a webapplication. You don't want to waste threads. If it is supposed to be used by a single concurrent user, then you should really ensure that the threadpool is properly [shutdown](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) at end of request or at highest end of session. But if it is supposed to be used by multiple concurrent users, then you'd like to share the threadpool in the application scope. Also here, you need to ensure that it is properly shutdown when the webapp shuts down. The `ServletContextListener` is useful here.

Answer (score 2):

If it is acceptable for you to use two connections, use connection pool [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) to manage them. To connect two databases I declare:

```
public Connection connection1;
public Connection connection2;
DataSource dataSource1;
DataSource dataSource2;
```

Then two similar methods:

```
public Connection dbConnect1() throws SQLException {
    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
    }
    cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase1?autoReconnect=true"); 
    cpds.setUser("myMYSQLServerLogin");
    cpds.setPassword("myMYSQLServerPassword");
    cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
    cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
    cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    cpds.setMaxIdleTime(60);
    cpds.setMaxStatements(100);
    cpds.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
    dataSource1 = cpds;
    connection1 = dataSource1.getConnection();
    return connection1;
}

public Connection dbConnect2() throws SQLException {
    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
    }
    cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase2?autoReconnect=true"); 
    cpds.setUser("myMYSQLServerLogin");
    cpds.setPassword("myMYSQLServerPassword");
    cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
    cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
    cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    cpds.setMaxIdleTime(60);
    cpds.setMaxStatements(100);
    cpds.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
    dataSource2 = cpds;
    connection2 = dataSource2.getConnection();
    return connection2;
}
```

Comment: Just do it in a cycle for your 350 databases. Extract parameters for each database from your main database if needed to clean up the code.

Answer (score 1):

As duffymo indicated in his comment, you will only be able to do transactions across multiple databases if you have a transaction coordinator and two phase commit.

For this you will need a J2EE stack that will handle JTA. If you are running in Tomcat or another container that does not have JTA, there are several options you can download and install.

Of course you will need to let the Container, not the database/stored procedure handle the transaction commits and rollbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a big mess, but it's your problem.

You need one connection pool per database.  I wouldn't advise that you try to handle the connection lifecycle yourself.  Let the app server do that for you.

If you want a group of databases to participate in one big transaction you'll have to use the JDBC XA drivers for *all* of them.  You'll also need a JTA transaction manager to oversee the transaction for you.

The stored procedures cannot contain any logic to handle transactions; you have to let JTA do it.

You don't say what the stored procedure is doing.  If it doesn't need to return anything, an alternative design might be JMS, a queue, and a listener pool.  I'd be worried about threading if I were you.  I'd find a way to let the container do that complicated stuff for meif I could.

Comment: I guess all the database connection urls are maintained in a central database. I believe we don't want to create datasources in the app server [as mentioned I have around 1 - 350 data sources].....in which case I guess I need to handle connection lifecycle myself right ?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static Connection getconnection(String db,String host){
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+**Pass Your Host Here 
Like Localhost**+"/"+Pass Your DB Name** +"?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF- 
8","root","root");
return con;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
} 
}
```

Comment: Writing code in answer is nice, but writing an explanation too of why this code works will be better [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers)