# How to setup cross region replica of AWS RDS for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, replication, rds

I have a RDS for PostgreSQL setup in ASIA and would like to have a read copy in US.

But unfortunately just found from the official site that only RDS for MySQL has cross-region replica but not for PostgreSQL.

And I saw [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/aws/rds-postgres-read-replicas/) introduced other ways to migrate data in to and out of RDS for PostgreSQL.

If not buy an EC2 to install a PostgreSQL by myself in US, is there any way the synchronize data from ASIA RDS to US RDS?

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on the purpose of your replication. Is it to provide a local data source and avoid network latencies ?

Assuming that your goal is to have cross-region replication, you have a couple of options.

#### Custom EC2 Instances

You can create your own EC2 instances and install PostgreSQL so you can customize replication behavior.

I've documented configuring master-slave replication with PostgreSQL on my blog: http://thedulinreport.com/2015/01/31/configuring-master-slave-replication-with-postgresql/

Of course, you lose some of the benefits of AWS RDS, namely automated multi-AZ redundancy, etc., and now all of a sudden you have to be responsible for maintaining your configuration. This is far from perfect.

#### Two-Phase Commit

Alternate option is to build replication into your application. One approach is to use a database driver that can do this, or to do your own two-phase commit. If you are using Java, some ideas are described here: [JDBC - Connect Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427817/jdbc-connect-multiple-databases)

#### Use SQS to uncouple database writes

Ok, so this one is the one I would personally prefer. For all of your database writes you should use SQS and have background writer processes that take messages off the queue.

You will need to have a writer in Asia and a writer in the US regions. To publish on SQS across regions you can utilize SNS configuration that publishes messages onto multiple queues: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html

Of course, unlike a two phase commit, this approach is subject to bugs and it is possible for your US database to get out of sync. You will need to implement a reconciliation process -- a simple one can be a pg_dump from Asian and pg_restore into US on a weekly basis to re-sync it, for instance. Another approach can do something like a Cassandra read-repair: every 10 reads out of your US database, spin up a background process to run the same query against Asian database and if they return different results you can kick off a process to replay some messages.

This approach is common, actually, and I've seen it used on Wall St.

---

So, pick your battle: either you create your own EC2 instances and take ownership of configuration and devops (yuck), implement a two-phase commit that guarantees consistency, or relax consistency requirements and use SQS and asynchronous writers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, I would like to provide a local data source in US site.

Comment: But create my own EC2 instances and install PostgreSQL would be my last choice because RDS service has perfect features like High Availability (Multi-AZ) and backup.

Comment: Ok, I agree. Let me amend my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is [now directly supported by RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/06/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-now-supports-cross-region-read-replicas/).

Example of creating a cross region replica using the CLI:

```sh
aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica \
    --db-instance-identifier DBInstanceIdentifier \
    --region us-west-2 \
    --source-db-instance-identifier arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:my-postgres-instance
```

Comment: Looks like you're referring to mysql, whereas the question was about Postgres.

Comment: @influent Just wrote the CLI command wrong, updated now. If you follow the link you can see the announcement about Postgres support.

Comment: Ohh thanks, I was thinking of master-master, which is still only available for mysql aurora.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it looks like this isn't supported anymore: `An error occurred (InvalidDBInstanceState) when calling the CreateDBInstanceReadReplica operation: Cross-Region Read Replicas are not supported for the provided source DB Instance engine version. Please upgrade to a supported engine version and try again.`  This is Aurora PostgreSQL v 10.11

Comment: That's because Aurora behaves differently to non Aurora RDS. You should raise a separate question about that and consider linking back to this one to show what you've tried.