# How to check if two columns are same/equal on not?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm looking for a way to check if two columns(c1 and c2) which belongs to two different tables (t1 and t2) are equal or not

But problem is both the tables (t1 and t2) are in two different databases(d1 and d2) on same server.

Would be great if you can provide a way using PreparedStatement in java.

Comment: put your solution and we will help

Comment: I do not have any solution yet.

Comment: `d1.t1.c1 = d2.t2.c2`

Comment: Well, there is no other way than to load each table (column) separately into memory, and compare programmatically.

Comment: @Nick Is it possible to specify a different DB within a JDBC call? Isn't JDBC connection bound to only one DB?

Comment: @ErShakirAnsari It seems Nick is right - according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html if you don't specify the database in the JDBC URL, you can use database name withing your SQL statement.

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427817/jdbc-connect-multiple-databases) will help get you the idea with @Nick comment and do your best..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `d1.t1.c1 = d2.t2.c2` as commented by @Nick?